# Show Column name in Document Library's View in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I'm using SP2013. When I use webpart to show the document library, it does not show the column name, i.e. FileName, Created, CreatedBy, Size, ...

[image]

Anyone knows how to show the column name?

thanks

Comment: Looking at how all the columns align quite badly in your screenshot, are you sure there is no custom CSS that fiddles with the list view?

Comment: no, I do not think so. I checked this on 2 sp2013 installation, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Edit WebPart-> in properties edit current view and then choose whichever column you want.

Comment: that's select columns, but does not show column title.